# ThreadSanitizer: signal handler spoils errno - how to avoid set of errno

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, posix

I have a bit of code which handles POSIX signals, and as part of it (to be signal safe) - does a sem_post() system call (according to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_post.3.html 'async signal safe').

But when I run this code - very occasionally, I get the thread sanitizer complaint:

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: signal handler spoils errno /home/lewis/Sandbox/Stroika-Build-Dir-Ubuntu1804_x86_64/Library/Sources/Stroika/Foundation/Execution/SignalHandlers.cpp:497 in Stroika::Foundation::Execution::SignalHandlerRegistry::FirstPassSignalHandler_(int)

I believe this is due to a call to sem_post, which may INDEED overwrite errno.

And yes - this could indeed mess up another thread if it happened at just the right (wrong?) time.

I've always found the 'thread local' errno mechanism a convenient way to handle errors, but I'm just now realizing how dangerous it is for signal handling code.

Is there some way to call system calls WITHOUT overwriting errno? Something at least vaguely portable?

Even http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html - says it stores its result in errno.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can use _syscall.
Another way would be to save errno at the beginning of the signal handler and restore before returning.
If you are sure that your function is safe in this respect you can also use some attributes (both in GCC and CLANG) to disable instrumentation of your functions.

Comment: according to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_syscall.2.html - Starting around kernel 2.6.18, the _syscall macros were removed from
       header files supplied to user space.  Use syscall(2) instead (and never worked on x64).

Comment: also, save and restore will still be a race/overwrite of errno.

Comment: errno is thread safe, signal handlers are executed in the context (same core so even same cache) of the thread handling the signal so a save/restore become not racy.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of that part (that while signal handler is running the thread isn't). Thanks.